# Hyperlinks in received emails always open same document from desktop. How to fix?

Tags: 12.04

Hyperlinks in received emails always open same document from desktop. how do I get links to open in firefox?

Comment: What do you mean by _Hyperlinks in received emails always open same document from desktop._ ? Is Firefox set up as your default browser?

Answer (score 0):

**To Set Firefox as default browser follow these steps:**

Open Firefox.
   In the top left corner there are 6 drop-downs. Open the second Drop-Down called *Edit*
   and then *Preferences* at the bottom of *Edit*.

[image: Firefox Preferences]

On the first page at the bottom you will find a button saying 
   *Make Firefox the default browser*

[image: default Browser]

After that your links should open automatically in Firefox.

Comment: Firefox was already default browser.The wrong link opens. The file:file:///var/lib/freegeek-extras/printme/index.html, opens, no matter what link was clicked.

Comment: That's odd... If you don't need that file on your desktop try and delete it.

Comment: Are you using Thunderbird?